# How to fix - Reload page,returns 404-not dound on React app,BrowserRouter.SSR.Rendertron

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, react-router, server-side-rendering

I used nginx and create SSR with rendertron in server, also install react app with BrowserRouter (becouse HashRouter doesn't be read in server side). But when I reload page in direct url (www.exaplme.com/some/direct/) it retuirn 404 page not found.

then I tried to try_files "try_files $uri /index.html;" in nginx it returns error:Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

```
NGINX:
server {
  ...
  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
}
Browse error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

I need to return the page where I reload, in hashRouter it works OK,but I need SERVER-SIDE(hash doesn't reads on ssr).

Comment: Do you use relative URLs for the resource files in `index.html`?

Comment: I use react-router to route to right path as like <Route path=“/anyparams/anypage” component={component}/> .